# Python Error Handling On Called Methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to continue my loop if the called method throws an exception. This is a simple example,my actual code is pretty complicated and do not want to put error handling in all the called methods.

```
list_of_lists = [['hammerhead', 'great white', 'dogfish'],[0, 1, 2],[9.9, 8.8, 7.7]]

def parse(item):
    item / 1

for list in list_of_lists:
    for item in list:
        try:
            parse(item)
        except ValueError:
            break
```

This throws an exception, as soon as it hits the parse method. I was hoping that there is a way, that it just moves on to continue my loop. (outer loop)

Comment: Trying to divide strings and ints should raise a `TypeError`.   Try `except (ValueError, TypeError):` to catch that as well.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, thank you for the response. This was just an example, is there a way to catch all possible error types. Provided methods are very big and complicated, and I am not sure what type of errors, they would throw.

Comment: Why not just `except:` without giving is a specific error (or list of errors) to handle?

Comment: Also, perhaps `continue` would be better than `break` if you don't want to end execution on the inner list.

Comment: python is giving a warning message saying (except is too broad which is not accepted by the rules of the company) .. and i would like the inner loop to end ( this was just an example, in our code, if inner fails, we have to move to the next item on the outer loop

Comment: Python isn't giving that warning message. Your IDE or editor does.  And it is a warning because usually you can't handle *all* possible exceptions in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are trying to divide a string by an int which raises a `TypeError` and not a `ValueError`, that's why your code throws an error.
If you want to catch all possible errors you can just do:

```
try:
    parse(item)
except:
    break
```

I wouldn't recommend it though, since in your case there seems to be a lot of complicated functions that can raise many different errors, it is probably better not to catch everything since you can miss an important error.
I would advise you to just run several times the code to find out all the possible errors and have a specific catch for every one, just to be sure there won't be an unrelated error you didn't anticipate

Comment: +1 one for not recommending to silently ignore all exceptions. This can make it very hard to find bugs that throw exceptions that are never seen. At least log them somewhere, including the traceback, before the `break`.  `logging.exception()` can be helpful here.